# MemSQL - clearing plancache across master and leaf nodes

Tags: mysql, database, singlestore

I have a MemSQL cluster that has one master aggregator and 3 leaf nodes. The master aggregator and 3 leaf nodes are each run on different servers so there are 4 servers in total.

Everyday there is a process that is run on the master aggregator servver which truncates all the tables in MemSQL and loads fresh data in from another source. After each table is truncated I drop the plancache via the following command:

```
memsqlcli="mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -vvv"
memsqlclid="$memsqlcli -D $memsql_db"
$memsqlclid -e "DROP ALL FROM PLANCACHE"
```

From reading the [MemSQL documentation](https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/reference/sql-reference/data-definition-language-ddl/drop-from-plancache/) on this function it appears I am only clearing the plancache from the current node (master aggregator). My understanding is that the leaf nodes should also have their cache cleared and faiure to do so could in turn cause some caching issues which I believe I am seeing sometimes in the data.

I have tried to find documentation on how to clear the cache across the whole cluster without any luck. Has anyone managed to implement a solution that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, DROP ALL FROM PLANCACHE operates on the node you are connected to only. To drop plancaches on all nodes, connect to all nodes and run this command. Unfortunately there is no command that performs this across the whole cluster.

What is your goal of dropping the plancache here? What do you mean by

> My understanding is that the leaf nodes should also have their cache cleared and faiure to do so could in turn cause some caching issues which I believe I am seeing sometimes in the data.

It is not normally necessary to explicitly clear plancaches, especially on the leaves.